# Angular5 how to get a variable reference from child component

Tags: angular, primeng

I'm using PrimeNG's data table with a global filter. I want the search input to be inside a child component.

PrimeNG enables globalFilter by doing this

having an input with a variable reference:

```
 <input #gb type="text" placeholder="Search">
```

and being used as the model for PrimeNG's globalFilter:

```
 <p-dataTable [globalFilter]="gb">
```

Is it possible for #gb to be inside a child component and be accessed in the parent?

Here's the [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/QcTZG0lXwLgUhyn3uVWD?p=preview). If you need more information please let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DataTable` is deprecated, use `TurboTable`. I guess you can get a reference of table component using `ViewChild('dt') dt: Table` and pass it to child and do `dt.filterGlobal($event.target.value, 'contains')`

```
<input (input)="dt.filterGlobal($event.target.value, 'contains')" type="text" pInputText >
```

If you can provide a plunker I can look at your exact issue.

---

Not sure if an `EventEmitter` approach will work unless `DataTable` exposes a `filter()` function. You can link to the `#gb` in `ChildComponent` directly if you want.

Here is an [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-hh28nd)

<kbd>child.component.ts</kbd>

```
import { Component, Output, EventEmitter, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'child-component',
  template: `<input #gb type="text" placeholder="Search">`
})
export class ChildComponent {
  @ViewChild('gb') gb: any;
}
```

---

<kbd>app.component.html</kbd>

```
<child-component #child></child-component>
<!-- You may as well need *ngIf="child.gb" in p-dataTable -->
<p-dataTable 
    [value]="data"
    [globalFilter]="child.gb.nativeElement">
```

---

No guarantees on how well this would work, better change to `TurboTable`, the trasition is not that tough as it might seem.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, unfortunately we can't switch yet to **TurboTable** since there's a lot of work to do before we switch over. Is it possible **to do this in the deprecated DataTable** ? I believe the 
`filterGlobal` method is not available on it.

Comment: Can you provide a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/pIHuiEKgaVzl009Xcd5j?p=preview) in your question with your DatatTable and child component setup? You can fork this. I can take a look.

Comment: Here's the [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/QcTZG0lXwLgUhyn3uVWD?p=preview). If you need more information please let me know

Comment: Check the updated answer and [this demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-hh28nd?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: You are awesome! Thank you so much